# how to save state in google action and dialog flow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am very confused by google documentation on dialogflow and actions for google. It looks like I need to mix and match between the two in order to implement some behaviors, like saving state between turns of a conversation.  For example, I have a dialog flow intent handler that looks like this

```
function showCard(agent) {
   let conv = agent.conv();
   if(!conv) console.log('There is no conv!'); // only assistant will have a conversation
   let n = 0;
   if(conv){
    if( !conv.user.storage ) conv.user.storage = {};
    n = conv.user.storage.cardNumber || conv.data.cardNumber || 0;
    console.log(`set cardNumber from ${n}`);
  }

// do some magic to generate a Card and simple response into _speakText

agent.add( _speakText );

if( conv ) {
    if( !conv.user.storage ) conv.user.storage = {};
    conv.data.cardNumber = n;
    conv.user.storage.cardNumber = n;
    console.log(`set cardNumber to ${n}`);
}
```

It looks like neither conversation or user data ever gets persisted. So how do I save state through the dialogflow API? What am I missing?

Is my confusion in that dialogflow examples demonstrate a different handler for requests/responses over actions on google?  (Should I yank out everything related to dialogflow agents?)

--- edit ---

```
 const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
 ...
 exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
```

OR

```
 const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');
 ...
 const app = dialogflow();
 exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the data in the session with the conversationToken. You can access to conversationToken through the conversational interface “conv.data” and then type the names of the parameters that you want to store. For example:

[image: Example to use conversationToken]

Through it you can save the data that you require to be kept in the same session of your Action. This also applies when you send a conversation from one device to another ([newSurface](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations)). But if you close your action, the session data will be lost.

Comment: I thought I did this in my pattern, but it is not persisted.  I've added an example of how I set up the request handler.  Dialogflow uses a webhook client (in the agent). Your example looks tuned to using a dialogflow object (in app). Can you mix patterns?  agents.add vs conv.ask ?

Comment: But your indicated pattern looks like you're using the previous version of the Google Assistant SDK. Regardless of the pattern, Google Assistant split the app object into a global app instance (that represents the Action itself) and a per conversation conv instance. I recommend you to separate these instances in order to have a specific context for Intent and thus save the data you need from the conv interface.

Comment: Clearing out the V1 / Dialogflow SDK calls fixed the issue. It looks like the Dialogflow doc and the boilerplate webhook need to all be updated to V2.  Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: And this parameter we are saving in contexts will be lost after the lifespan of context, right?
How can we save data throughout one conversation, just like `conv.data` in case of `actions-on-google` `conversation` object?

Comment: In that case you have two options, if you want to manage data outside of the conversation you have the "userStorage" to which you can access like this: conv.user.storage, with it you can save data inside the device even when your conversation is finished until it is invoked again. On the other hand, if you want to keep information between users and synchronized, I recommend you to use firebasestore to have something more structured.